# PostgreSQL update or insert multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Quick question regarding "upsert" in PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (id, name, telephone)
VALUES (1, 'John', '930823088'), (2, 'Laura', '008905238')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
```

now by adding SET I can set the values, but that would be for the entire table. How do define to set the values per row, so that if id 1 exists, the update inserts the first row of values, if 2 exists, it uses the 2nd row?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) that's what the `excluded` pseudo-row is for:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (id, name, telephone)
VALUES (1, 'John', '930823088'), (2, 'Laura', '008905238')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
  set name = excluded.name, 
      telephone = excluded.name;
```